# Renaming matrix and scalar in loop

Tags: r

I'm trying to make a loop, which changes the name for every iteration. The code is shown below. So what I basically need is for instance for a=2, I want W_(a-1) to refer to a matrix called W_1, W_(a) to refer to a matrix called W_1 and finally GMM_(a-1)$par should refer to GMM_(1)$par.

```
for (a in 2:100){
    GMM <- function(beta) {
        for (i in 1:(nrow(gmm_i))){
            gmm_i[i,] <- g_beta(i,beta)
        }
        gmm_N <- t(colSums(gmm_i)) %*% W_(a-1) %*% colSums(gmm_i) 
        W_(a) <<- solve((1/(nrow(A)/5))*t(gmm_i)%*%gmm_i)                     
        return(gmm_N)
    }
    GMM_(a)<-optim(GMM_(a-1)$par,GMM)
}
```

I hope my question makes sense.

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at `assign` ?

Comment: Make your life easier and use lists.

Comment: I started using R a week ago. Can you relate it to my current problem?

Comment: Make `GMM` a list and access it using `GMM[[a]]`. The same for `W`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want 100 variables(a1,a2 ....) in your workspace? It will be better if you put all of this in a list as it will be easy to use. But if for some reason you do want a bunch of variables then use this,

```
W_1 = 0
for (a in 2:100){
  GMM <- function(beta) {
    for (i in 1:(nrow(gmm_i))){
      gmm_i[i,] <- g_beta(i,beta)
    }
    gmm_N <- t(colSums(gmm_i)) %*% W_(a-1) %*% colSums(gmm_i) 
    tmp <- solve((1/(nrow(A)/5))*t(gmm_i)%*%gmm_i)
    assign((paste("W_",a,sep="")),tmp,envir=.GlobalEnv)
    return(gmm_N)
  }
  tmp1 <- optim(GMM_(a-1)$par,GMM)
  assign((paste("GMM_",a,sep="")),tmp1,envir=.GlobalEnv)
```

GMM_(a)<-
    }

Give W_1 appropriate value.